# Change the bottom line color for SwiftUI toolbar(NavigationBar)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Problem**: I would like to change the navigation bar bottom line color or remove it I would like to use SwiftUI API to achieve that.

**I would like to keep the toolbar background color white and keep it visible all the time**

[image: toolbar_color]

**Code that you might use an example**:

```swift
struct ToolbarBackgroundColor_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Change the color of bottom of this line ☝️")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Test")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                .background(.white)
                .toolbarBackground(.white, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar, .tabBar)
            }
    }
}
```